When using pkg to package a Node.js program, I encounter a mkdir issue
I'm making a script that runs the JSON output of the Youtube Data API.
I want to make the program runable without installing node.js
So ncc+pkg is used to package it.
ncc is used here because axios cannot be packaged simply with pkg.
This is my output method
const exportJsonFile = (dataItems, playlistId) => {

    const outputDir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'output');
    console.log(outputDir);
    const fileName = `playlist_${playlistId}.json`;
    const filePath = path.join(outputDir, fileName);
    
    if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(outputDir, { recursive: true });
    }
    
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(dataItems, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, jsonData);
    console.log(`已經輸出至 ${filePath}`);
    askPlaylistId();
};

The outputDir part originally used __dirname
Keep encountering problems with mkdir
After searching for information, I found that it was caused by snapshots.
You should switch to using process.cwd() to obtain the path.
After doing this initially, you can package and use it normally.
But when I adjusted the program and packaged it again
I started to encounter problems with mkdir again.
I tested the path of outputDir through console.log
I found that it was not in the folder where I ran the program.
Instead, it's in the C://snapshot
How do I deal with it?

thank , it work now.

could you specify which code worked, because when tried to reproduce, your example with process.cwd() worked instead of process.argv..
